# Using wget to download images from a webpage

Tags: image, download, wget

I tried to download all the images from a given URL using wget. Below are some of the commands I had used.

```
wget -A.jpg [URL]
wget -A .jpg [URL]
wget -A *.jpg [URL]
wget -A .jpg [URL]
wget -nd -r -P /my/directory/ -A jpeg,jpg [URL]
```

Non of the above commands worked. So to make sure, i checked the file extensions of each images from the URL I specified and realized they are formatted as this:

```
URL/image.jpg?quality=85&strip=info&w=1200
```

How can i work around this issue where there are parameters at the end of a file extension from the URL i tried to retrieve from? Is there an option in wget that I am missing?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put an asterisk after `jpg` too, if you want to match those files that doesn't end with `jpg`.

Like:

```
wget -A *.jpg* [URL]
```

You can also use regex patterns with the `--accept-regex` argument if you want more complex filtering.